# boost thread move assignment vs. move constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, doc

The Boost.Thread library specification for the move constructor states for

Move Constructor:

> Effects: Transfers ownership of the
>   thread managed by other (if any) to
>   the newly constructed boost::thread
>   instance.

whereas for Move Assignment :

> Transfers ownership of the thread
>   managed by other (if any) to *this. 
>   If there was a thread previously
>   associated with *this then that thread
>   is detached.

Clearly, for move assignment it is explicitly stated that previous thread object becomes detached.

Since the copying of boost::thread object has not been defined, and only moving of ownership is possible, does this mean that with Move Constructor, the previous owner thread does not become detached?

Or is this simply a documentation oversight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding. Label your thread objects A and B, and the actual thread T.

If B owns T, move constructing A from B means A now owns T, and B owns nothing.
If B owns T, move assigning A from B means A now owns T, and B owns nothing, *and whatever A had previously owned is not owned by anything* (aka, detached).

Comment: You're right, on second read I do see I misread the documentation. Thanks for the very nice example though :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a move-*constructor* -- what previous owner can there be if the object is just coming into existence?

Comment: Apparently, there can be another owner of the thread, not thread object : thread(detail::thread_move_t<thread> other);

Comment: @Jas : I have no idea what you mean by that or how you think it relates to your question. `detail::thread_move_t` is a type that allows for emulation of C++11 move semantics in C++03; it has nothing to do with logical thread ownership.

Comment: I just didn't find the ildjarn's answer helpful, that's all.

Comment: @Jas : I guess saying something that assumes the reader possesses at least *some* critical thinking skills isn't always safe. ;-] (And, explaining why `2 + 2` == `4` gets tedious.)

Comment: @ildjarn - And I assume that asking a concrete question will not yield smart-ass comments, but actual concrete answers (see other two answers for explanation). I clearly *misunderstood the documentation* as GMan HELPFULLY highlighted, which was not case with your "critical thinker" answer mockery.

Comment: @ildjarn - I also hope you won't re-edit your last comment for the fourth time, just to post your personal rant w/o connection to actual question.

Comment: @Jas : If you're implying that what I said is fundamentally different than what Bo said, I have to agree -- I assumed that the reader has some basic knowledge of C++. My mistake.

Comment: I'm implying that unlike you, the two other guys were actually TRYING TO HELP, instead of just showing off a bit.

Comment: And cut the crap on basic knowledge of C++ please, I already said I clearly did misread the documentation. At least I'm not acting all-knowing.

Comment: @Jas : And I'm not pretending to be psychic. Get over it.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that when move constructing, the new thread object didn't exist before, so it has no previous thread.

When move assigning, you start with two thread objects and end with at least one of them being empty.